# Panda: Groupby external Trigger (timeseries)

Tags: python, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have the result of some Time-series analysis in a dataframe: In irregular periods (depends on the time a vehicle is driving) there was build the sum over the distance a vehicle mad within this time.

Now I like to compare this results with another dataset. But in this second dataset, I have a regularly timestamp every minute. So I easily got the daily sum of the distances within this second dataset.

So, first I just create a groupby on both datasets, grouped by the date. Sometimes that looks fine, but from time to time, the vehicle drive over midnight.

I already grabbed the end-time of the last track of every day out of the first dataframe and now I would like to use this last timestamp of the day as a external trigger so build a groupby on my new dataset, so I again can build a sum.

Here I try to construct a sample-Dataset, as long as the real Data would be to big to fit in here, I put this example together by hand:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'StartData': ['2018.12.02 23:08:59', '2018.12.02 23:12:25'], 
'EndDate': ['2018.12.02 23:08:59', 2018.12.03 00:15:58],
'DistanceTrack': [5.01900, 72.00100]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018.12.02 23:48:00', '2018.12.02 23:49:00', '2018.12.02 23:50:00', '2018.12.02 23:51:00', '2018.12.02 23:52:00','2018.12.02 23:53:00', '2018.12.02 23:54:00', '2018.12.02 23:55:00', '2018.12.02 23:56:00', '2018.12.02 23:57:00', '2018.12.02 23:58:00', '2018.12.02 23:59:00', '2018.12.03 00:00:00', '2018.12.03 00:01:00', '2018.12.03 00:02:00', '2018.12.03 00:03:00', '2018.12.03 00:04:00', '2018.12.03 00:05:00', '2018.12.03 00:06:00', '2018.12.03 00:07:00', '2018.12.03 00:08:00', '2018.12.03 00:09:00'],
'km': [113117, 113118, 113119, 113120, 113121, 113122,113123, 113124, 113125, 113126, 113127, 113128, 113129, 113130, 113131, 113132, 113133, 113134, 113135, 113137,113138,113139]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the first dataset to your preference [Pandas time man](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Hmm, that did not help. Converting to datetime is not the point, I already did that. Grouping one timeseries by the timestamp of another timeseries with a different frequency of time or, with an irregular periods, that is the point